# How to add a row and have the last column be a copied formula in google docs?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

In a Google docs spreadsheet I have rows of students where each column is a test score:

```
Student | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Average
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
Jane    | 100%   | 50%    | 75%    | 75%
John    |  60%   | 70%    | 80%    | 70%
```

The last column, `Average`, is a formula. When I want to add a new student, I simply write their name and test scores. What I want is to have the `Average` column's formula copied automatically. I don't want to have to copy it manually. The reason is other people will be entering the information through forms and other mechanisms.

Is this possible?

It would even be ok if the user had to insert a row at the top or any other position instead of adding the student at the end.

Comment: Do you have some experience programming in JavaScript? You can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here a very basic example that shows what you can achieve with Apps Script to get what you need. I hope you find it useful.

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function onEdit(e) {
  var id_sheet_apply_change = 1139;
  var cell, row, strrow, range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetId() === id_sheet_apply_change) {
    row = range.getRow(); strrow = row.toString();
    cell = range.getSheet().getRange(row, 5);
    if (!cell.getFormula())
      cell.setFormula('IFERROR(AVERAGE(B' + strrow + ':D' + strrow + '); "")');
  }
}
```

**Stage 0:**

[image]

**Stage 1:** When you finish editing the first column (A), is added the formula in the corresponding cell (E).

[image]